# Fastest way to list all the annotated methods in annotated classes

Tags: java, reflection

DISCLAIMER: "Fastest" here refers to execution time.

I'm trying to list all the methods annotated by `M` if they are within classes annotated by `C`.

I know I can get a list of classes using `Reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith` and then iterate over the classes asking each method if it is annotated by `M`. But I wonder if this is the fastest way to do so!

Comment: You'll probably have to research and benchmark this yourself...  what research have you done so far?

Comment: @JimGarrison I've posted this question here. Come on man, I'm not asking for some algorithm tuning advice! I'm just trying to find the proper way of using a library.

Comment: I've been working a lot with reflection lately on advanced and exotic use-cases. I can't really guarantee you're right, but I believe the way you explained is the only one.